# Getting One Image Src to Change with JQuery when Another Image is Clicked

Tags: jquery, image, src

I'm creating a product view with one big image above a row of smaller images.  The big image should change when one of the little images is clicked (to have the src of whichever small image was clicked).

My HTML is:

```html
<img id="MainProductImage" src="Images/Product Images/AB04_GRAY_22A6_W_WEB.jpg">

<img id="sm001" src="Images/Product Images/AB04_G.jpg">
<img id="sm001" src="Images/Product Images/AB04.jpg">
<img id="sm002" src="Images/dB 002.jpeg">
<img id="sm003" src="Images/dB 003.jpeg">
<img id="sm004" src="Images/dB 004.jpeg">
```

My jquery is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('img.sm001').click(function() {
  $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'Images/Product Images/AB04_G.jpg')
 });
 
 $('img.sm002').click(function() {
  $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'Images/Product Images/AB04.jpg')
 });
 
 $('img.sm003').click(function() {
  $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'Images/dB 002.jpeg')
 });
 
 $('img.sm004').click(function() {
  $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'Images/dB 003.jpeg')
 });
 
 $('img.sm005').click(function() {
  $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'Images/dB 004.jpeg')
 });
});
```

How can I get this to work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect selector. You need to use id `#` selector instead of class selector `.` as elements have ids like `sm001`,`sm002`....`sm005`:

```
$('#sm001').click(function() {
    $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'Images/Product Images/AB04_G.jpg')
});
$('#sm002').click(function() {
    $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'Images/Product Images/AB04.jpg')
});

$('#sm003').click(function() {
    $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'Images/dB 002.jpeg')
});

$('#sm004').click(function() {
    $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'Images/dB 003.jpeg')
});

$('#sm005').click(function() {
    $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'Images/dB 004.jpeg')
});
```

Also you can narrow down the whole click events code to single event.

```
$('img[id^=sm00]').click(function() {
    $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting wrong element using class `img.sm001`, try id instead `#sm001` and so on for the rest:

```
$('img#sm001')
```

try this code:

```
$(function(){

    var main = $('#MainProductImage');//get the object once

    //target is imag tag, where id starts with `sm00`
    $('img[id^=sm00]').on('click', function(){
        main.prop('src', this.src);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please find the code with few changes that is working

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#sm001').click(function() {
  $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'grapes.jpeg')
        alert($('#MainProductImage').attr('src'));
 });
 
 $('#sm002').click(function() {
  $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'apple.jpeg')
         alert($('#MainProductImage').attr('src'));
 });
 
 $('#sm003').click(function() {
  $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'banana.jpeg')
         alert($('#MainProductImage').attr('src'));
 });
 
 $('#sm004').click(function() {
  $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'mango.jpeg')
         alert($('#MainProductImage').attr('src'));
 });
 
 $('#sm005').click(function() {
  $('#MainProductImage').attr('src', 'strawberry.jpeg')
         alert($('#MainProductImage').attr('src'));
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <img id="MainProductImage" src="fruits.jpeg">

<img id="sm001" src="grapes.jpeg">
<img id="sm002" src="apple.jpeg">
<img id="sm003" src="banana.jpeg">
<img id="sm004" src="mango.jpeg">
<img id="sm005" src="strawberry.jpeg">
```

I hope it helps .please read the following [JQuery selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) that helped a lot for me in understanding the selections.